# Momentary switch as GPIO input - Trouble with code and bouncing/floating

Tags: gpio, python

**Update** So this is now the code I'm running. It now works but is bouncing/floating. - I believe this can be controlled within the code itself by looking for an edge value as opposed to a high or low, OR it can be controlled with a resistor in the hardware.

```
    import os, RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.IN)

while True:
   if(GPIO.input(22) == GPIO.LOW):
      print ("22 Input")
      # more code for pin 22 here
   elif(GPIO.input(23) == GPIO.LOW):
      print ("23 Input")
      # more code for pin 23 here
   elif(GPIO.input(24) == GPIO.LOW):
      print ("24 Input")
      # more code for pin 24 here
```

**Original Post**
Could someone please help me write a python script. I'm using a 3 momentary button switches as inputs and I'm really struggling with the code. I understand there are a lot of tutorials on this but I can't seem to get it right!

here's a picture of how I have my 3 buttons wired up    -     https://learn.adafruit.com/system/assets/assets/000/024/487/large1024/raspberry_pi_pi_jukebox_buttons_bb.png?1429117506

I've been through two python scripts that looked promising but they kept floating/bouncing

Also is it a good idea to use GPIO.cleanup() even if the program is meant to be running all the time?

Extra points if it starts on boot and runs in the background :P

I'm running Wheezy, and thank you so much guys this community is amazing.

I've tried two different bits of code.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from time import sleep

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    if (GPIO.input(22) == False):
        os.system('echo hello &')

    if (GPIO.input(23) == False):
        os.system('echo hello &')

    if (GPIO.input(24)== False):
        os.system('echo hello &')

    sleep(0.1);
```

Also I've tried this code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import  os
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setop(22, GPIO.IN)
while True:
    if GPIO.input(22):
    os.system("echo hello")
    prev_input = input
time.sleep(0.005)
```

Comment: As the wiring diagram appears correct, your software must be at fault.

Comment: Hi Joan, thank you. I believe this to be the case also. I am having trouble with my python scripts.

Comment: If you post a script for reading one switch we may be able to help.

Comment: Certainly, bear with me 10 minutes I'll post them up. Thanks!

Comment: Edit your original post and add the code with the {} in the middle top of the edit area.

Comment: Glancing at the some of [the documentation](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) for that python module, I think you should be using the `wait_for_edge` methodology and not what is described there as "polling" in a loop.

Comment: Conceptually I'm fine with what bounce is and why we look for changes in state as opposed to absolute values. But I don't know how to write code. I really don't. It's literally another language to me. I figured I could find a template for button inputs (then put my own commands within it and make it work). I'm sorry if that sounds like a lazy cop out but I've actually put quite a bit of time and effort into my project and this coding is killing me.

Comment: @joan - I think I'm making headway. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19534/multiple-inputs-through-gpio?rq=1   At the end of that article (you're there funnily enough) it's found to be GPIO.input == False doesn't work, it should be GPIO.input == GPIO.low):     Just going to check it now. I think this will be the problem. I still don't quite get how to use GPIO.cleanup() or if it's really needed for something like this that'll be always on

Comment: I just updated my main post. So I have the code working now but I'm having bounce/floating issues.

Comment: To re-iterate a point more strongly: Polling in userspace (particularly with sub 10 ms sleeps) when you can wait passively, indefinitely, on an interrupt from kernelspace is *just silly*.   So rather than coming up with the "right" way to do things wrongly, you might want to consider aiming for the right way to do things the right way.   Which is do not loop checking a gpio for changes of state.  Block waiting for a callback.

Comment: thanks goldilocks, I think the problem lies in I can't code. If I have this right... I'm constantly checking the state of a GPIO pin wasting resources and having problems on account of it. You're suggesting I use a block waiting for a callback? - I'll have to google that I have no idea what that is

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I would say you are doing everything right :)
With such simple connection you are bound to get debouncing and you can solve it with software - by adding hysteresis.
There is a tutorial on [debouncing](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5780/debouncing.pdf) that might come handy in solving the problem.
For additional help - it would be nice if you could post the code, so we can help you with that. 
You can also see hardware solution to debounce effect in the attached document.

Comment: I just added the code, thanks for helping. I found that article a bit heavy to be honest. I'm not really much of a programmer. From what I know the bounce should be stopped by having a resistor in the circuit and/or by looking for a trailing edge instead of a HIGH or LOW.